# Is there a way to write data to parquet files if I don't know the schema before hand using Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, parquet, flink-streaming

I have multiple event streams and I constantly keep integrating new kinds of events into my Kafka streaming layers. I currently have 3 different types of complex events coming in from my web streams and I am planning on integrating 6 more over this year. Is there a way to write all these data streams to parquet without me having to configure multiple flink datastreams for each topic with a predefined schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple side outputs, each for a specific event type with it's own configured parquet writer. For each different event, you can provide a different schema.

Comment: Unfortunately that would mean stopping my pipeline every time I need to add a new source. The effort is very repetitive. Plus I would want a reflect of my schema instead of me figuring out how it looks and adding a schema.

Comment: I'm not sure  how you will handle the new models on fly, but in case you manage to do it, you can provide your custom implementation of `BulkWriter.Factory`, which will be responsible for building customized `ParquetWriter` instance. This one can build an `AvroParquetWriter` instance with a generic schema: `AvroParquetWriter
      .builder[T](out)
      ....
      .withSchema(ReflectData.get.getSchema(schemaType))
      .withDataModel(ReflectData.get())
      .build`